# Can I traverse the entire WORD array of 4 elements with QWORD PTR?

Tags: assembly

I want to change values of all `WORD` array of 4 elements by one step using `QWORD PTR`

```
mov ebx, OFFSET arr ; arr is WORD of 1,2,3,4 
xor qword ptr [ebx], 8000800080008000h ; I get error of constant value too large
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `xor` specification, that you can see [here](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xor), there is no version of xor with `imm64` - an immediate value of 64 bits.

You can do something like this:

```
mov rcx, 0x8000800080008000
xor qword ptr [rbx], rcx
```

Note that the register in the `xor` command must be r64 type (`rax`, `rbx`, ...) and not the r32 type (`eax`, `ebx`, ...)

Comment: Thanks for your informative reply. Unfortunately, I am required to reverse a specific bit on each element with ONE instruction step. The first thing that came in my mind is to use qword ptr to address the entire array 4 elements ( 8 bytes) then using XOR which is the only instruction can reverse bit at once as I know as a basic student of Assembly.

Comment: I believe it could be only 2 elements be changed at a time and I tried it and it worked if I use XOR DWORD PTR [EBX], 80008000h and if I need to change the other 2 elements I should adjust the address [EBX+ or- 4].